# Meteor JS get the url who requested in the server publish method

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, coffeescript

How can I get url information who requested in the server publish method? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I will answer my own question. You can used this command

```
this.connection.httpHeaders.host
```

Comment: Note that this only returns the hostname, not the url.